# Angular2: Bind observables to input form fields

Tags: angular

I've built an observable like this:

```
this.source$ = this.store$
  .select(state => state.source);
```

In template:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="input-to" placeholder="To" [ngModel]="(source$ | async).customer" name="sender" class="input-transparent form-control">
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see I'm trying to "bind" `$source` `Observable` t a form input field.

Currently, I'm getting this exception message:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./PaymentForm class PaymentForm - inline template:21:13 caused by: valUnwrapper.unwrap(...) is null

Another question. Could somebody tell me how to bind observables into input fields? I mean, should I use `[ngModel]="(source$ | async)..."` or `(ngModel)=...`

Answer (score 3):

`ngModel` is used only for *two way binding*.Its syntax is `[(ngModel)]`
For one way value binding use `[]` from component to html.
Try value:

```
 <input type="email" id="input-to" placeholder="To" [value]="(source$ | async).customer" name="sender" class="input-transparent form-control">
```

`()` is used for binding from view to component (e.g. events).
Example

```
<input type="email" id="input-to" placeholder="To" (onChange)="func()" name="sender" class="input-transparent form-control">
```

You can use `ngModel` like `[ngModel]="data" (ngModelChange)="event()`